# Change the row and column focus of a GridLayout on Navigation button pressed.(up,left,down,right)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tv

```
   switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            {

         //I want the focus to move to the focus to the cell above the current cell
            break;
        }
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
        {
             //I want the focus to move to the focus to the cell which is  below the current cell
            break;
        }
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
        {
              //I want the focus to move to the focus to the cell which is the to the right of the current cell
            break;
        }
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
        {

             //I want the focus to move to the focus to the cell which is  below the current cell
            break;
        }


    }
```

I am trying to change the focus inside a Gridlayout, from one tile to the another on a remote's navigation button pressed. But I don't know the syntax to get the current location of the focus. I want the index of the cell of the gridlayout to which the focus is, so that I increment or decrement its count to move from one cell to another. Can anyone please help.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added the code, and the functionality I want to happen .. on the click of four navigation button.

Comment: You really need to provide more details, like the "remote" code buton you refer as well as the layout xml, otherwise we can't help...

Comment: I haven't defined anything in the xml. I have a Grid layout in Andeoid TV launcher. And I want the focus to change from on cell to another. For focus change I have added a simple code("on focus")  in xml..at image background.